# to create a multi filter column using the ItemTemplate and from the Enum Data, But ItemTemplate function is not being called

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-grid

I am trying to create a multifilter from enum data type column using the Item Template. But Item Template JavaScript function is not being called and data is not being shown in combo box for some reason. I am looking for a help from expertise to solve.

**Enum Records**

```
public enum EmpTypes
{
    [Display(Name = "Service")]
    Service = 0,
    [Display(Name = "Sales")]
    Sales = 1,
    [Display(Name = "Purchase")]
    Purchase = 2,
    [Display(Name = "Office")]
    Office = 3
}
```

**Kendo Grid**

```
columns.Bound(c => c.EmpTypes).Title("Type")
        .Filterable(filterable => filterable
            .Multi(true)
            .UI("").DataSource(s=>s.Read(r=>r.Action(“GetEmpTypes”,”Report”)))
            .ItemTemplate(“typetemplate”));
<script>
 function typetemplate(e)
{
  alert('Test');
}

</script>
```

**Action Method in MVC controller**

```
Public ActionResult GetEmpTypes()
{
 List<EmpType> emptypes = new List<EmpType>();
emptypes.Add(EmpType.Sales)
emptypes.Add(EmpType.Report)
return Json(emptypes,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```